# What should I write in my thank you letter to CEO?

Tags: software-industry, student, masters

I have been working as R & D engineer in a company for the past 2 years during my study. I recently graduated from university and the same company hired me as a full time employee. Our CEO sent a group message congratulating me for getting my degree.

I think I need to write a thank you letter. But I have no clue what to say. How should I write a short thank you letter? How can I express my acknowledgement of the help I received from the other colleagues?

Here is what I prepared:

> Hello CEO,
>
> Thanks for your kind words and for extending your support towards
> obtaining my degree. Everything I have learned in the last 2 years has
> been extremely helpful in achieving this milestone and I owe it to you
> and all my colleagues and mentors here.  I look forward to our mutual
> success!(or Looking forward to continuing my learning journey at xyz
> company.)
>
> Kind regards,  XYS

Comment: How big is your company? 10 people or 1000 people?

Comment: Personally, I think the moment has probably already passed. If it was a group chat, you probably should have just said "Thank you. I really appreciate all the help everyone has given me". If it was an email, then there is still time... just reply with a short message saying thanks. Keep is short, informal, and just be yourself letting your personality into your reply will be better received than any "robot" type reply will ever be. There is no need to make it sound overly professional.

Comment: 201-500 employees

Comment: it is an email.

Comment: @happypumpkin: Is the email addressed to everyone in the company, or just people specific to your area? When replying to an email, it is best to use the "reply to all" feature. Then the same people who got the original will be the ones that see your reply.

Comment: @happypumpkin: Also, how long ago was the email sent? And have you already replied to it saying thanks?

Comment: no i have not yet. 4 hours.

Comment: @musefan Please do NOT recommend the use of "reply all". I might have been slightly interested to see the congratulatory email. I would not be at all interested to see the recipient thanking the CEO for it.

Comment: @DJClayworth: And if you want to thank the whole team for their support? Are you just going to expect the CEO to pass that on for you? The question specifically says "How to acknowledging the help of others?", so it's fair to assume this response is meant for multiple people.

Comment: If you want to thank the whole team, then send the email to the whole team. But if you want to thank the CEO (including telling the CEO that other people helped you) then send it to the CEO.

Comment: @DJClayworth: If the notice went out to the whole company, then I agree that "reply all" is a bad idea. If the notice went out to a select group, it's not necessarily a bad thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like:

Dear CEO,

Thanks for your kind words and extending your support towards obtaining my degree. Everything I have learnt in last 2 years, have been extremely helpful in achieving this milestone and I owe it to you and all my colleagues and mentors here. Looking forward to continue my learning journey at XXX company.

Regards,

Happy Pumpkin

Comment: Is not that "my degree"? you wrote "your degree"

Comment: @happypumpkin Corrected!!

Answer (score 1):

Writing a personal thank you letter for a quick and short group email might be seen as overkill, or trying to be obsequious.

A simple reply (not "reply all") email of thank you, and how pleased you are to be on board is appropriate given the amount, or lack thereof, personal effort the CEO put into it.

Just a couple of quick sentences is fine, I'd think.